# how to solve Component should be written as a pure function error in eslint-react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

```
const Header = React.createClass({
  contextTypes: {
    router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  },

  render() {
    return (
        <li className={this.context.router.isActive('a') ? 'active' : ''}>
          <Link to="/a/">A</Link>
        </li>
        <li className={this.context.router.isActive('b') ? 'active' : ''}>
          <Link to="/b/">B</Link>
        </li>
    );
  },
});
```

I use eslint-config-airbnb to check the above code and it show me an error msg like Component should be written as a pure function .

So how to change the above component to pure function?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

When you have a "dumb" component (no internal state, lifecycle methods, etc.), you may write it as a simple javascript function as opposed to using `React.CreateClass` or extending `React.Component`.

Check out the docs [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html) for general information on pure functions as components and [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) for information specific to `context`.

So in your case:

```
function Header(context) {
  return (
    <li className={context.router.isActive('a') ? 'active' : ''}>
      <Link to="/a/">A</Link>
    </li>
    <li className={context.router.isActive('b') ? 'active' : ''}>
      <Link to="/b/">B</Link>
    </li>
  );
}

Header.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}
```

Comment: I try that and in header function context Object have only get key and get ref property, router is undefined.

Comment: Did you include the Header.contextTypes line as well?

Comment: Yes i include that line.

Comment: Hmm, it should work. Did you change this.context.router to just context.router? I've updated my answer with the complete code, I was unclear about what to do with your render method

Comment: I just copyed that code and I get 'Cannot read property 'isActive' of undefined thet error', also router is undefined.

Comment: Perhaps you can create a simple runnable example

Answer (score 0):

You could also try the ES6 way:

```html
const Header = (context) => (
  <li className={context.router.isActive('a') ? 'active' : ''}>
    <Link to="/a/">A</Link>
  </li>
  <li className={context.router.isActive('b') ? 'active' : ''}>
    <Link to="/b/">B</Link>
  </li>
);

Header.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}

export default Header;
```

Answer (score -1):

I use some fake props to bypass this error:

```
export default class NavItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { count: 0 };
  }

  render() {
    const { router } = this.context;
    const { index, onlyActiveOnIndex, to, children } = this.props;
    const isActive = router.isActive(to, onlyActiveOnIndex);
    const LinkComponent = index ? IndexLink : Link;
    return (
      <li className={isActive ? 'active' : ''}>
        <LinkComponent to={to}>{children}</LinkComponent>
      </li>
    );
  }
}

NavItem.propTypes = {
  children: React.PropTypes.node.isRequired,
  index: React.PropTypes.bool,
  onlyActiveOnIndex: React.PropTypes.bool,
  to: React.PropTypes.oneOfType([
    React.PropTypes.string,
    React.PropTypes.object,
  ]).isRequired,
};
NavItem.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.object,
};
```

Comment: This is not best practice.