# Is it possible to decorate a react class written as a pure render function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux, eslint

Say that a React class is defined as a pure function, as described [in this article](https://medium.com/@joshblack/stateless-components-in-react-0-14-f9798f8b992d) and [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37598415/how-to-solve-component-should-be-written-as-a-pure-function-error-in-eslint-reac). For example:

```
const Text = ({children}) =>
  <p>{children}</p>
```

instead of

```
class Text extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <p>{this.props.children}</p>;
  }
}
```

Can the component defined as a pure render function be still decorated?

For example, I can decorate the class using `connect` from `react-redux` and `bindActionCreators` from `redux`:

```
@connect(
  state => someSelectors(state),
  dispatch => bindActionCreators(someActions, dispatch)
)
class Text extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <p>{this.props.children}</p>;
  }
}

export default Text;
```

Would decorating the version written as a pure function work as expected? In particular, will this work:

```
//Text.js

const Text = ({children}) =>
  <p>{children}</p>

export default connect(
  state => someSelectors(state),
  dispatch => bindActionCreators(someActions, dispatch)
)(Text);
```

When I try to compile some code implemented like in the example above I am getting the [`import/no-named-as-default-member`](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-named-as-default-member.md) error from ESLint in `index.js` that tries to import the exported decorated function:

```
//index.js
import Text from 'Text.js'; // <= error: import/no-named-as-default-member
```

It seems that [decorating functions in JavaScript](http://raganwald.com/2015/06/28/method-decorators.html) should be possible with the Babel transpiler. But even if that function was decorated properly, would React still use it correctly? The ESLint error is a bit worrying.

Comment: If the rule you linked triggers on that code, the rule appears to be buggy. There's nothing wrong with the code you've shown, and neither are you accessing a property on the default export nor does your module have any named exports.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that the code is OK. There must be some error in that rule, or maybe in Webpack or Babel, because I copied the file and renamed the exported name in it and I couldn't replicate the problem (I wanted to isolate the problem to raise an issue). Then I deleted the additional file and that specific error stopped appearing in the original file as well. Strange.